# Spin, Tumble and Wobble in Regular Polyhedra

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Because of its uniform distribution of mass, any line passing through a sphere's center of mass can be used as a spin axis, and the sphere will not exhibit secondary wobble or a chaotic tumble.

Under what conditions can similar spin stability be expected with regular polyhedra?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [intermediate axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem) any object with three distinct principal mass moment of inertia values, rotation about the intermediate axis is going to be unstable.

So to ensure stability you need a body with at least one symmetry axis that would yield only two values for MMOI, and thus just a min and max value with no intermediate axis.

Answer (score 0):

All regular polyhedra have three equal principal moments of inertia, $I_1 = I_2 = I_3$. This follows from their high degree of symmetry.   This means that (effectively) any axis of the body is a principal axis, and the polyhedron will rotate stably about any axis in the body frame.